# Spring batch partition execute 1 step endlessly(many many times - loop)

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I have a folder which contains bunch of xml files. I want to configure partitioning to create many partitions, each partition will process a configurable number of files. The partitioner work fines (I check in the debug mode and it return the proper execution contexts). But the thing is the step is being execute many times despite of number of execution contexts created by the partitioner. In this example I only have 3 xml files. Each partition will process 2 files.
I upload the whole project to github: https://github.com/tungtran89/spring-batch-partition

Please give me advices, thanks!

This is the partitioner

```
public class FilePartitioner implements Partitioner {

private String xmlFolderLocation;
private int filePerThread;

@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Assert.hasLength(xmlFolderLocation);
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> executionContexts = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    File xmlDir = new File(xmlFolderLocation);
    if (xmlDir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = xmlDir.listFiles();
        int fileCount = 0;
        int totalFileCount = 0;
        int partitionCount = 0;
        Map<String, String> chunk = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (File file: files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                if (fileCount < filePerThread && totalFileCount < files.length) {
                    totalFileCount++;
                    chunk.put(file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath());
                    fileCount = chunk.size();
                }
                if (fileCount == filePerThread || totalFileCount == files.length) {
                    // load enough file to this partition.
                    // create a new partition by creating new ExecutionContext and new chunk
                    partitionCount++;
                    ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext();
                    stepExecutionContext.put("chunk", chunk);
                    chunk = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    executionContexts.put(String.valueOf("partition" + partitionCount), stepExecutionContext);
                    fileCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return executionContexts;
}
```

}

The spring configuration file

```xml
 <bean id="filePartitioner" class="com.tung.FilePartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="xmlFolderLocation" value="target\test-classes\data\XML_FILES"/>
    <property name="filePerThread" value="2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlLoadReader" scope="step" class="com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader">
    <property name="chunk" value="#{stepExecutionContext['chunk']}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="xmlProcessor" scope="step" class="com.tung.XMLPrintingFileProcessor"/>
<bean id="xmlWriter" scope="step" class="com.tung.XMLPrintingWriter"/>

<bean id="xmlLoadTaskExecutor"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<batch:step id="slaveStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="xmlLoadReader" processor="xmlProcessor" writer="xmlWriter" commit-interval="5"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<batch:job id="xmlLoader">
    <batch:step id="master">
        <batch:partition step="slaveStep" partitioner="filePartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="2" task-executor="xmlLoadTaskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The reader

```
public class XMLPrintingLoadReader implements ItemReader<List<File>> {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XMLPrintingLoadReader.class);
private static int instanceCount = 0;
private int readMethodInvocationCount = 0;
private final int instanceId = instanceCount;

private Map<String, String> chunk;

public XMLPrintingLoadReader() {
    instanceCount++;
}

@Override
public List<File> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    synchronized (this) {
        readMethodInvocationCount++;
    }
    logger.info("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is invoking method read() " +
            "of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[" + instanceId + "] " + readMethodInvocationCount + " times.");
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : chunk.entrySet()) {
        File file = new File(entry.getValue());
        fileList.add(file);
    }
    return fileList;
}

public Map<String, String> getChunk() {
    return chunk;
}

public void setChunk(Map<String, String> chunk) {
    this.chunk = chunk;
}
```

}

The log files:

```
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 1 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 1 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 2 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 2 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 3 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 3 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 4 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 4 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 5 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 5 times
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 6 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 6 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 7 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 7 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-1 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[0] 8 times.
INFO  XMLPrintingLoadReader:37 - Thread xmlLoadTaskExecutor-2 is invoking method read() of com.tung.XMLPrintingLoadReader[1] 8 times.
```

Comment: ItemReader must return null to stop reading process. If list is empty return null and not the empty list

Comment: Luca, can you take a look at the source code and help me. https://github.com/tungtran89/spring-batch-partition

Comment: did you try `return fileList.isEmpty() ? null : fileList;`

Comment: Hi Luca, the thing is why the task executor's thread keep invoking the reader so many times. The partitioner only create 2 execution context so I suppose the step should be execute 2 times no matter what the fileList is empty or not. By the way, I try your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: The work around is check if the invocation count of read() method is more than 1 then return null immediately.